# Different servers for AngularJS and PHP?

Tags: angularjs, rest, laravel, jsonp

I am starting to develop a web application that has AngularJS frontend and Laravel backend. At this stage I have two directories in my XAMP htdocs - one is for AngularJS project that is served by grunt embedded server on localhost port 9000 and other project is Laravel that is served by XAMP Apache/PHP on localhost post 8081. I see problems with $http requests to the other Laravel application and other urls from the outer internet that I am using as test url's - apparently this is due to cross-site security protection

That leads me to the question - **is it possible to have two servers (or at least one server with different ports - each port can be served by different server) for frontend/backend application?** I know that this is possible for GET requests that should be replaced by JSONP requests. But what about other HTTP verbs - are there $http methods that can make PUT, DELETE and similar requests to the other server or to the other port of the same server/application?

Or the only possibility is to run both frontend and backend on the same server/port in the same application. That means that I should host AngularJS as part of PHP or Java application and not use grunt for this, is it so?

The initial problem arouse from famous Angular JS http status -1 error. I am closely following tutorial http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-5-angularjs-tutorial and my code is:

```
return $http({
    method: 'GET', //'JSONP',
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/testserver/server.php/api/v1/contracts',
    //url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    timeout: 100000
  }).then(function(result) {
      alert(result);
      return result.data;
    },
    function (error) {
      alert(error);
      console.log("v2 my object: %o", error);
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  );
```

When I make request to the localhost, the -1 error is present, but my request to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts gives expected answer. I tried to use my external IP address instead of localhost but the error was still present. My server side code apparently uses Laravel Illuminate ->get() function that, I presume, do all the conversion necessary for converting array of Contract objects into JSON response:

```
public function index($id = null) {
    if ($id == null) {
        //this branch is being tested 
        return Contract::orderBy('CONTRACT_NO', 'asc')->get();
    } else {
        return $this->show($id);
    }
}
```

There is not anything exception about server response - it is JSON array:

```
[{"CONTRACT_NO":"1","CUSTOMER":null,...}]
```

Comment: You need to look at CORS requests

Comment: My initial problem is AngularJS http status -1 famous problems. I thought that it is connected with CORS, but my Angular is running on http://localhost:9000/#/contracts and it made successful request to 'url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'' but it throws http status -1 for the localhost Laravel service. I am not sure whether is this is or isn't CORS

Comment: Can you post some code showing how you're making your request client side, and how you're trying to handle it server side

Comment: When you do a GET in your browser to http://localhost:8081/testserver/server.php/api/v1/contracts do you get the expected response?

Comment: Of course I tried to put this url in my Chrome address bar and there was this white page with simple text - JSON response. I guess it should have been GET request and I don't bother about headers I guess the default values are sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware) to handle CORS requests. Without anything similar you won't be able to support CORS requests made to your Laravel backend.

Try using something like the following - this is currently set to allow any origin request, during production you'd probably want to tighten this up to only allow requests from known sources.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Response;

class CorsMiddleware {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // setup array of CORS headers
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'   => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'  => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'  => 'Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization, X-Requested-With',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'  => true,
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => 'Authorization',
        ];

        // check for OPTIONS request
        if( $request -> getMethod() == 'OPTIONS')
        {
            return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
        }

        // add CORS headers to remaining requests
        $response = $next($request);
        foreach( $headers as $key => $value )
        {
            $response -> headers -> set($key, $value);
        }

        return $response;
    }

}
```

You could also look at this package for adding CORS support to Laravel: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: That was it! This was the right solution. Middleware should be registered in app/Http/Kernel.php

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by configuring virtual hosts on the Apache server. The differentiation can be done by using different domain names (or subdomains), IP addresses, or ports.

Example configuration on ports 80 and 8080:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/domain-80"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:8080>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/domain-8080"
</VirtualHost>
```